# Why the react native deep linking to FB opens my home instaead of the page i have passed

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

I  have passed a fb page like this " 
        Linking.openURL("fb://page/XXXXXX") ", 
but when opens the app it's showing my home page.

This is how i have passed the page

```
  "  Linking.canOpenURL("fb://page/XXXX").then(supported => {
    if (supported) {
    return Linking.openURL("fb://page/XXXX");
    } 
     else {
     return Linking.openURL("https://www.facebook.com/");
    }
     })   "
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">     
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
 <data android:scheme="fb" android:host="page" />
 </intent-filter>
```